# How to count new appearances of an item in SQL?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have an Orders table with fields:
user_id, created_at.

I want to create a query that shows how many NEW user_ids appeared per day.

This shows how many orders there were per day:

```
SELECT
  count(1), TO_CHAR(created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as day
FROM
  orders
GROUP BY
  day
ORDER BY
  day DESC
```

Comment: So this is MySql I'm guessing? (since it's allowing column aliases to be used in the `Group By`, which most do not)

Comment: @JW웃 - [Postgres has a `TO_CHAR` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/functions-formatting.html) too.

Comment: Oh my bad. I'm know only little amount of functionality in postgresql.

Comment: ... and Oracle as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT count(1),
       TO_CHAR(FirstOrder, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS day
FROM   (SELECT MIN(created_at) AS FirstOrder,
               user_id
        FROM   orders
        GROUP  BY user_id) first_orders
GROUP  BY TO_CHAR(FirstOrder, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
ORDER  BY day DESC
```